# Join details from two lines based on a match of the first two or three fields

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I'm seeking help to extract / merge data from a single csv file.

The file contains the arrival and departure times of ships over a few months. The details of the arrival and departure are on separate lines (carriage return) and the fields separated by commas. Some of the fields are repeated.

I would like to merge the two lines (into one line), only keeping the unique fields, and output the results to a file. A ship can have multiple stops into Port i.e. different dates so I think a search might use the first two or three fields (the date, vessel and maybe the IMO number) to find the corresponding line?

Here is a small sample of the data.

```
Date,Vessel,IMO_No,Agent1,Move,Berth,Time,FromPort,ToPort,Trade
6 Nov 23,Royal Princess,9584712,MCKAY,Arrival,Beach Street,12:15,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE
6 Nov 23,Royal Princess,9584712,MCKAY,Departure,Beach Street,21:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE
19 Nov 23,Grand Princess,9104005,MCKAY,Arrival,Beach Street,07:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE 
19 Nov 23,Noordam,9230115,MCKAY,Arrival,C/T,08:00,Fiordland,Timaru,CRUISE 
19 Nov 23,Grand Princess,9104005,MCKAY,Departure,Beach Street,18:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE 
19 Nov 23,Noordam,9230115,MCKAY,Departure,C/T,18:00,Fiordland,Timaru,CRUISE
```

Ideal Output file

```
6 Nov 23,Royal Princess,9584712,MCKAY,Arrival,Beach Street,12:15,Departure,21:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE
19 Nov 23,Grand Princess,9104005,MCKAY,Arrival,Beach Street,07:00,Departure,18:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE
19 Nov 23,Noordam,9230115,MCKAY,Arrival,C/T,08:00,Departure,18:00,Fiordland,Timaru,CRUISE
```

Note: I assume the solution can reorder or remove fields.

I've scoured the web for hints and tips. Suggestions including AWK, SED and GREP but it's been a while since I've used these commands and I've only managed to get part way into the goal (after 4 hours so far). I'm hoping someone more competent at programming / scripting might find this trivial and simple to do.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Where is Ubuntu in that question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider taking a database approach to something like this. For example, using `csvsql` from the Python-based [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) (available as package `csvkit` from the Ubuntu `universe` repository):

```
csvsql --no-inference --query '
  SELECT a.Date,a.Vessel,a.IMO_No,a.Agent1,a.Move,a.Berth,a.Time,d.Move,d.Time,a.FromPort,d.ToPort,a.Trade
  FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM file WHERE Move = "Arrival") a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM file WHERE Move = "Departure") d 
  ON 
  a.Vessel = d.Vessel AND a.IMO_No = d.IMO_No
' file.csv
Date,Vessel,IMO_No,Agent1,Move,Berth,Time,Move,Time,FromPort,ToPort,Trade
6 Nov 23,Royal Princess,9584712,MCKAY,Arrival,Beach Street,12:15,Departure,21:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE
19 Nov 23,Grand Princess,9104005,MCKAY,Arrival,Beach Street,07:00,Departure,18:00,Fiordland,Lyttelton,CRUISE 
19 Nov 23,Noordam,9230115,MCKAY,Arrival,C/T,08:00,Departure,18:00,Fiordland,Timaru,CRUISE
```

Note that I omitted the constraint `a.Date = d.Date` since it seems possible that a vessel might depart on a later day - if that's true, you may wish to add `d.Date` to the selected output fields.

Alternatively you could use a tool like [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/) to convert your CSV to a structured form such as JSON, then use [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to manipulate it.

Comment: Thank you Steeldriver. I'll give your suggestion a go.